# Is the comma in the sentence: 'His is the Yorkshire Terrier, the one with the red collar' correct?

Tags: punctuation

Is this comma correct or should it be a colon?

Comment: The comma's fine; a colon or dash would work, too. All three mark what follows as a supplement or enlargement of what comes before.

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon is ordinarily used either as a 'hinge' between independent clauses or as a 'conjunction' in a list composed of elements which themselves contain commas.

In your sentence there's no list, and *the one with the red collar* is not a clause but an appositive noun phrase, a supplement added to give more details about *the Yorkshire Terrier*. Supplements are ordinarily bracketed off from the main clause with pairs of commas or dashes, or single points if the supplement falls at the beginning or end of the sentence. At the end of the sentence you may also use a colon for a somewhat more emphatic pause, as if you're drawing your hearer's attention to the dog.

Answer (score -1):

For this sentence, you want a ***semicolon***.

> His is the Yorkshire Terrier; the one with the red collar.

---

- A ***semicolon*** is used for a pause. This would be more pronounced
  than a comma would indicate.
- A ***colon*** would be used if what followed was a list, a definition or quote.
- A ***semicolon*** is also used to combine to clauses/ideas into one single
  sentence.
- A ***comma*** would be used in the middle of a sentence. The dictionary defines it as: Comma (,) A comma marks a slight break between different parts of a sentence. Used properly, commas make the meaning of sentences clear by grouping and separating words, phrases, and clauses.

---

Please let me know if this help or if you need further assistance!

Comment: I think not. A semicolon is used as a 'hinge' between independent clauses, or as a 'conjunction' in a list composed of elements which themselves contain commas. Here the NP *the one with the red collar* is an appositive supplement further specifying *the Yorkshire Terrier*; it may be attached with a comma, a colon or a dash.

Comment: It's also my opinion. A semicolon here is non-standard.